# Postsharp support for visual studio 2017 , 2019 and 2022

Tags: postsharp

One of our application framework we are using postsharp version 6.3.13 which is supporting us on Visual studio 15 , 17 and 19.  Is there any postsharp stable version available which can support for Visual studio 17 , 19 and 22 .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the last version (PostSharp 6.11) support Visual Studio 2022.4.

Comment: PostSharp 6.11 doesn't support VS 2017. For 2017+2019+2022, you can use PostSharp 6.10. This one doesn't support .NET 7, but neither do Visual Studios 2017 and 2019.